# httpd workes become zombie process

Tags: php, apache, docker, unix, zombie-process

I am running a php service in a docker container via apache + mod_php. For some reason sooner or later I get "Service unavailable" on reverse proxy. Inspecting the container I always find that all httpd workers became zombies and are no longer reaped by master process. I assumed it was due to zombie reaping issues in docker containers and attempted to solve it by adding tini as pid 1. Unfortunately it didn't solve the issue, I suppose because httpd master process is still running, so workers are actually not orphans to be reaped by pid 1. At this point I have no ideas on how to approach this problem and thus ask for your assistance.

Does anyone know how to debug this kind of issue?

Below is the output of the 'top' command run inside of container. I use plain alpine as base image with php7 installed via 'apk'.

```
    9     1 root     S     169m   1%   3   0% /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 5493     0 root     S     1592   0%   1   0% sh
 5501  5493 root     R     1524   0%   2   0% top
    1     0 root     S      760   0%   0   0% /sbin/tini -- /usr/sbin/httpd -D F
 5484     9 apache   Z        0   0%   3   0% [httpd]
 5492     9 apache   Z        0   0%   0   0% [httpd]
 5485     9 apache   Z        0   0%   0   0% [httpd]
 5490     9 apache   Z        0   0%   3   0% [httpd]
 5486     9 apache   Z        0   0%   0   0% [httpd]
 5487     9 apache   Z        0   0%   1   0% [httpd]
 5483     9 apache   Z        0   0%   3   0% [httpd]
 5482     9 apache   Z        0   0%   1   0% [httpd]
 5489     9 apache   Z        0   0%   1   0% [httpd]
 5491     9 apache   Z        0   0%   3   0% [httpd]
 5488     9 apache   Z        0   0%   0   0% [httpd]
```

Comment: **1**: does it do that with simple static, only HTML content?  That would indicate a PHP code issue (infinite loop of some kind?).  Thus debug PHP.  **2** What MPM module do you use?  Show us your configurations: which MPM, what performance parameters are set.  I am curious at `MaxConnectionsPerChild`.  Set it different than 0 so the master process kills and start new child processes once in a while.

Comment: **3** since you talk of a proxy, the child processes are waiting for a response from some backend server.  If you set the timeouts to 0, and the backend does not respond, the processes will appear stuck and do nothing.

Comment: @Nic3500 The service itself is not a reverse proxy. I just use it as a router to the service itself.